# I am working in one project in which duplicate key:twitter occer.I can't solve this error in Android studio

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mysocialreader"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

configurations
        {
            all*.exclude module: 'gson';
            all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
            //  all*.exclude  module: 'iofabricsdkandroid_fabric'

                compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"

            all*.exclude  module: "iofabricsdkandroid_fabric_2"
        }

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'


    compile files('libs/scribe-1.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric-classes.jar')


    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2-with-sources.jar')



    compile(files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar'))

    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0') {


        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude(group: 'com.google', module: 'gson')
    }
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.0')
            {
                exclude(group: 'com.google', module: 'gson')
                exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
            }
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.19.0')
            {
                exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
                exclude(group: 'com.google', module: 'gson')
            }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.google', module: 'gson'
            }

    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.google', module: 'gson'
            }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.google', module: 'gson'
            }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0')
            {
                exclude group: 'com.google', module: 'gson'
            }

//    compile project(':iofabricsdkandroid_fabric_2')

    compile project(':facebookSdk')
    compile project(':diffHeightsGridView')
    compile project(':vKOpenAuthActivity')

    compile project(':comtwittersdkandroid_twitter_2')


}
```

Comment: could u post your full logcat errors ?

Comment: yes thanks...Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/twitter/sdk/android/BuildConfig.class     ......

Comment: I got this error when I run my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your terminal.

Go to your root project folder.

```
./gradlew clean
```

And also add this to your configuration part in build.gradle file.

```
all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Again got same Issue..I tried all solutions  this same project works fine in eclipse but, not in android studio. please suggest me other solution.   Thank you.

Comment: have you tried ./gradlew clean from your terminal and also clean and build your project.

Comment: Yes sir, I use your solution properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this in Android Studio by going to Build>Clean Project